# How would I parse strings in c and ignore a certain word in that string?

Tags: c

How would I parse strings in c to ignore certain characters?

Say I have code that contains the word, "contain", so basically:

```
 contains blah sdkld sldksdk
 contains dksld sldkd tkel
```

So basically, I want to get:

```
blah sdkld sldksdk
dksld sldkd tkel
```

Comment: 1: Input a word. 2: Does it contain the word you're blocking? 3: If not, print the word. 4: Repeat. (If you need help turning that into C code, you'll have to make a bit more effort. Please take a look at the [help] pages and edit your question to include the code you've written so far and explain why it isn't working how you expected.)

Comment: This question doesn't show much research effort. I count at least 4 posts in the *Related* list over there --->>> that could potentially help you, and that's just the ones that this site found when you posted this question. Imagine what you might be able to find if you did a search here yourself and read some of the results of that search.

Answer (score -2):

you can split word, later eval the val return:

http://c.conclase.net/librerias/?ansifun=strtok